# Convergence of a normalized random series

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X_k)_k$ be a sequence of independent random variables. Suppose that there exists a sequence $(\alpha_k)_k$ of real numbers such that $\sum_k(X_k-\alpha_k)$ converges a.s.

Does it follow that $$\sum_k P(|X_k-E[X_k1_{\{|X_k|\leq 1 \}}]|>1)<\infty \ \text{and} \ \sum_k Var((X_k-E[X_k1_{\{|X_k|\leq 1 \}}])1_{\{|X_k-E[X_k1_{\{|X_k|\leq 1 \}}]| \leq 1\}})<\infty \ ?$$

I tried to use the three series theorem. The problem is how to remove $\alpha_k$ ?

Any suggestions a welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_k=a_k=k$ for all $k$ then $\sum (X_k-a_k)$ converges a.s. but the first series is divergent.